# JSTL fmt:parsedate of pubDate attribute in RSS 2.0

Tags: jsp, parsing, date, jstl

I need to parse this String in order to convert it to Date:

```
Tue, 3 Sep 2013 19:47:52 +0200
```

I'm using

```
<fmt:parseDate var="parsedDate" value="${pubDate}" type="both"/>
```

but the result is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;,
value attribute can not be parsed: "Tue, 3 Sep 2013 19:04:18 +0200"
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: It is parsed another value.

Answer (score 0):

`<fmt:parseDate>` is going to attempt to parse the date based on the *locale*. You can see what this is likely to be via `<fmt:formatDate>`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="both"/>
```

I'd recommend using an explicit pattern:

```
<fmt:parseDate var="parsedDate" value="${pubDate}" 
    pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"/>
```

(the patterns letters are from [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a workaround by using the same `type` or `pattern` attributes in both `fmt:format` and `fmt:parse`.

> for example 
>   suppose we have a current date object as
>   `<% pageContext.setAttribute("date", new Date()); %>`

- `<f:formatDate value="${date }" pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" var="fmt_date"/>`
- `<f:parseDate value="${fmt_date }" pattern="dd-mm-yyyy" var="parse_date"/>`

> OR you could try with type as `both` or `time` or `date`.

- `<f:formatDate value="${date }" type="both" var="fmt_date"/>`
- `<f:parseDate value="${fmt_date }" type="both" var="parse_date"/>`

> hope it helps.!